# Read lines containing certain numbers

Tags: python

So, here is what I want to do:
I have two sets of data text files. The first set contains data looking like this:

```
timestamps  parameter
151 152     700
153 154     701
155 156     702
157 158     703
```

Where the first and the second column are timestamps, the third is a pramater.
The second set of data looks like this:

```
timestamp       data value
154.2           +6.0087e-03
155.5           +8.3871e-03
155.7           +5.9500e-03
158             +1.5245e-02
```

Where the first column contains timestamps, the second a data-value.

So, what I want to do now is the following: I want to read the timestamps for a certain parameter, let's say for example timestamps for the parameter 702 (so 155 and 156). Then I want to take those timestamps and add all data-values inbetween those timestamps to an array (so in this example the array would be:

```
array = [+8.3871e-03, +5.9500e-03]
```

So, I want to do this for actually every line of set one, which means parameters from 700 to 1100, so that I get an array of data-values for every of those parameters. I want to process the Data further then, but first I need to get a solution for that problem, but I don't really have a good idea. I am thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you actually done anything to try and solve this problem yourself? Have you read the file in?

Comment: Do you know how you want to do this?

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You are expected to start your project and when you get stuck post your code and ask a *specific* question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have recognized that I only need the first entry in each line of the first set, so the first timestamp. And this way, I found a fairly simple solution that seems to work. It looks like this:

```
pyro01 = np.loadtxt('pyro_eins.dat')
pyro_run01 = []
data01 = np.loadtxt('wavelengths_eins.dat')
    for line in data01:
        pyro_run01.append(np.average(pyro01[pyro01[:,0] == int(line[0])][:,-1]))
```

Where pyro_eins is the second set (with data values) and wavelengths_eins is the set with the parameters and timestamps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
parameters = {int(i[-1]):i[:-1] for i in [b.strip('\n').split() for b in open('file1.txt')][1:]}
datavals = {a:b for a, b in [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('file2.txt')][1:]}
parameter = 702
final_arrays = [b for a, b in datavals.items() if float(a) >= float(parameters[parameter][0]) and float(a) <= float(parameters[parameter][-1])]
```